# Gpower: Correlational power analysis

Tags: correlation, statistical-power

I would like to perform a power analysis on Gpower. The only bit of information that I have is provided in the image below: [image]

This is what I have done so far:

[image]

Am I doing it right ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's a very high power (it's GPower's default). Typically people use 0.8 or 0.9.

You should probably set the tails to be two. (Again, that's a weird GPower default).

I'm assuming that $\beta$ in the image is a standardized effect.